Drawing an image with ILI9341 Display And STM32F103C8T6
[pic1]
[pic2]
i am trying to draw this image in the ili9341 diaplay, but as you can see the colors are broken and i dont know how to fix.
also this is the C array of the image: link
i generated the array using lcd image converter software and put the hex data inside the C array

The shape of the picture is correct. It seems like the color values are off. Instead of setting red value for the pixel, you set blue value with the value that was supposed to be red intensity value.
What you think you're doing, for one pixel:
R: 255  
G: 128  
B: 0  

How the display interprets your data:
B: 255 //you think you set red, but you actually set blue  
R: 128  
G: 0

The solution is to transform that image into RGB values, but shuffle around the values of R, G and B (and A, if it's there). One of the combinations will almost certainly give you the expected image. If you use some automatic tool to generate RGB values (which is reasonable), configure it to output color values in a different order (as BGR, RBG, etc.).
